# How do I select a range of rows between two values using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to slice sample data at the bottom...

So that each session (Session - events from login through action before next login) that looks like this:

```
login,4,2016-11-10 05:28:30.396,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getUserPreferences,179,2016-11-10 05:28:30.575,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getPreference,3,2016-11-10 05:28:55.686,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getPreference,4,2016-11-10 05:28:55.961,hbhimani,11/10/2016
constructFromSession,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.108,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getUserPreferences,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.112,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getUserPreferences,3,2016-11-10 05:28:56.116,hbhimani,11/10/2016
setBooleanPreference,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.238,hbhimani,11/10/2016
setBooleanPreference,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.513,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getQuickSearchInitInfo,3,2016-11-10 05:28:58.936,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getQuickSearchInitInfo2,4,2016-11-10 05:28:59.315,hbhimani,11/10/2016
```

I would like to count number of records and the occurrence of getPreference action.  Will appear as one record that looks like this:

```
day,User,session_duration(min),getPreference_count,total_session_actions
11/10/2016,hbhimani, 180, 2, 11
```

My challenge is occurring when I have more than one session.  I don't know how to slice dynamically on index.

Sample Data:

```
Action,Duration,_time,User,day
login,4,2016-11-10 05:28:30.396,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getUserPreferences,179,2016-11-10 05:28:30.575,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getPreference,3,2016-11-10 05:28:55.686,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getPreference,4,2016-11-10 05:28:55.961,hbhimani,11/10/2016
constructFromSession,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.108,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getUserPreferences,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.112,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getUserPreferences,3,2016-11-10 05:28:56.116,hbhimani,11/10/2016
setBooleanPreference,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.238,hbhimani,11/10/2016
setBooleanPreference,4,2016-11-10 05:28:56.513,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getQuickSearchInitInfo,3,2016-11-10 05:28:58.936,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getQuickSearchInitInfo2,4,2016-11-10 05:28:59.315,hbhimani,11/10/2016
login,3,2016-11-10 05:29:29.202,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getSummary,4042,2016-11-10 05:29:33.246,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getEnclosures,457,2016-11-10 05:29:34.372,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getAuditTrail,1061,2016-11-10 05:29:36.034,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getRelatedDefects,5,2016-11-10 05:29:36.586,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getServiceRequests,5,2016-11-10 05:29:36.864,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getForeignBugs,270,2016-11-10 05:29:37.408,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getEnclosures,455,2016-11-10 05:29:50.087,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getSummary,5505,2016-11-10 05:32:26.584,hbhimani,11/10/2016
getEnclosures,459,2016-11-10 05:32:27.940,hbhimani,11/10/2016
login,997,2016-11-10 05:32:29.480,anshanno,11/10/2016
getRelatedDefects,5,2016-11-10 05:32:30.027,anshanno,11/10/2016
getServiceRequests,5,2016-11-10 05:32:30.306,anshanno,11/10/2016
getForeignBugs,6,2016-11-10 05:32:30.585,anshanno,11/10/2016
```

Comment: Because it's not designed to work that way? What exactly is your question? Read up about slices. Especially how they work with `pandas` data structures.

Comment: You question looks like a [XY problem question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Could you post a desired data set (`day,User,session_duration(min),getPreference_count,total_session_actions`) based on your sample data set?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I looked and didnt see anything similar to what I am trying to do.

Comment: @MaxU Thanks, I am not really familiar with the XY problem - so I tried to clarify and add my desired output more explicitly.  I could probably just convert the series to a matrix and count since that's really all I need to do now that I think of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can group your data as follows:

Original DF:

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
                     Action  Duration                   _time      User        day
0                     login         4 2016-11-10 05:28:30.396  hbhimani 2016-11-10
1        getUserPreferences       179 2016-11-10 05:28:30.575  hbhimani 2016-11-10
2             getPreference         3 2016-11-10 05:28:55.686  hbhimani 2016-11-10
3             getPreference         4 2016-11-10 05:28:55.961  hbhimani 2016-11-10
4      constructFromSession         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.108  hbhimani 2016-11-10
5        getUserPreferences         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.112  hbhimani 2016-11-10
6        getUserPreferences         3 2016-11-10 05:28:56.116  hbhimani 2016-11-10
7      setBooleanPreference         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.238  hbhimani 2016-11-10
8      setBooleanPreference         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.513  hbhimani 2016-11-10
9    getQuickSearchInitInfo         3 2016-11-10 05:28:58.936  hbhimani 2016-11-10
10  getQuickSearchInitInfo2         4 2016-11-10 05:28:59.315  hbhimani 2016-11-10
11                    login         3 2016-11-10 05:29:29.202  hbhimani 2016-11-10
12               getSummary      4042 2016-11-10 05:29:33.246  hbhimani 2016-11-10
13            getEnclosures       457 2016-11-10 05:29:34.372  hbhimani 2016-11-10
14            getAuditTrail      1061 2016-11-10 05:29:36.034  hbhimani 2016-11-10
15        getRelatedDefects         5 2016-11-10 05:29:36.586  hbhimani 2016-11-10
16       getServiceRequests         5 2016-11-10 05:29:36.864  hbhimani 2016-11-10
17           getForeignBugs       270 2016-11-10 05:29:37.408  hbhimani 2016-11-10
18            getEnclosures       455 2016-11-10 05:29:50.087  hbhimani 2016-11-10
19               getSummary      5505 2016-11-10 05:32:26.584  hbhimani 2016-11-10
20            getEnclosures       459 2016-11-10 05:32:27.940  hbhimani 2016-11-10
21                    login       997 2016-11-10 05:32:29.480  anshanno 2016-11-10
22        getRelatedDefects         5 2016-11-10 05:32:30.027  anshanno 2016-11-10
23       getServiceRequests         5 2016-11-10 05:32:30.306  anshanno 2016-11-10
24           getForeignBugs         6 2016-11-10 05:32:30.585  anshanno 2016-11-10
```

group it:

```
In [63]: grp = df.groupby(['User', df.Action.eq('login').cumsum()])
```

print all groups:

```
In [64]: for g, x in grp:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
                Action  Duration                   _time      User        day
21               login       997 2016-11-10 05:32:29.480  anshanno 2016-11-10
22   getRelatedDefects         5 2016-11-10 05:32:30.027  anshanno 2016-11-10
23  getServiceRequests         5 2016-11-10 05:32:30.306  anshanno 2016-11-10
24      getForeignBugs         6 2016-11-10 05:32:30.585  anshanno 2016-11-10
                     Action  Duration                   _time      User        day
0                     login         4 2016-11-10 05:28:30.396  hbhimani 2016-11-10
1        getUserPreferences       179 2016-11-10 05:28:30.575  hbhimani 2016-11-10
2             getPreference         3 2016-11-10 05:28:55.686  hbhimani 2016-11-10
3             getPreference         4 2016-11-10 05:28:55.961  hbhimani 2016-11-10
4      constructFromSession         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.108  hbhimani 2016-11-10
5        getUserPreferences         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.112  hbhimani 2016-11-10
6        getUserPreferences         3 2016-11-10 05:28:56.116  hbhimani 2016-11-10
7      setBooleanPreference         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.238  hbhimani 2016-11-10
8      setBooleanPreference         4 2016-11-10 05:28:56.513  hbhimani 2016-11-10
9    getQuickSearchInitInfo         3 2016-11-10 05:28:58.936  hbhimani 2016-11-10
10  getQuickSearchInitInfo2         4 2016-11-10 05:28:59.315  hbhimani 2016-11-10
                Action  Duration                   _time      User        day
11               login         3 2016-11-10 05:29:29.202  hbhimani 2016-11-10
12          getSummary      4042 2016-11-10 05:29:33.246  hbhimani 2016-11-10
13       getEnclosures       457 2016-11-10 05:29:34.372  hbhimani 2016-11-10
14       getAuditTrail      1061 2016-11-10 05:29:36.034  hbhimani 2016-11-10
15   getRelatedDefects         5 2016-11-10 05:29:36.586  hbhimani 2016-11-10
16  getServiceRequests         5 2016-11-10 05:29:36.864  hbhimani 2016-11-10
17      getForeignBugs       270 2016-11-10 05:29:37.408  hbhimani 2016-11-10
18       getEnclosures       455 2016-11-10 05:29:50.087  hbhimani 2016-11-10
19          getSummary      5505 2016-11-10 05:32:26.584  hbhimani 2016-11-10
20       getEnclosures       459 2016-11-10 05:32:27.940  hbhimani 2016-11-10
```

Explanation:

```
In [71]: df['grp_id'] = df.Action.eq('login').cumsum()

In [72]: df[['Action','User','grp_id']]
Out[72]:
                     Action      User  grp_id
0                     login  hbhimani       1
1        getUserPreferences  hbhimani       1
2             getPreference  hbhimani       1
3             getPreference  hbhimani       1
4      constructFromSession  hbhimani       1
5        getUserPreferences  hbhimani       1
6        getUserPreferences  hbhimani       1
7      setBooleanPreference  hbhimani       1
8      setBooleanPreference  hbhimani       1
9    getQuickSearchInitInfo  hbhimani       1
10  getQuickSearchInitInfo2  hbhimani       1
11                    login  hbhimani       2
12               getSummary  hbhimani       2
13            getEnclosures  hbhimani       2
14            getAuditTrail  hbhimani       2
15        getRelatedDefects  hbhimani       2
16       getServiceRequests  hbhimani       2
17           getForeignBugs  hbhimani       2
18            getEnclosures  hbhimani       2
19               getSummary  hbhimani       2
20            getEnclosures  hbhimani       2
21                    login  anshanno       3
22        getRelatedDefects  anshanno       3
23       getServiceRequests  anshanno       3
24           getForeignBugs  anshanno       3
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have a quick follow up question that may or may not be best to ask here....in the for loop I do my calculations and then append each df to a list and concatenate them back into a single df.  Is this going to be scalable?

Comment: @anshanno, well it depends... The first thing you want to check when using Pandas is whether you can avoid loops - if your task can be solved without using loops (vectorized approach) - it's the best option. In general collecting DFs in a list and concatenate them using `pd.concat(list_of_DFs)` - is a standard and idiomatic pattern, unless it doesn't fit into your RAM